# rails table will only seed nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, seeding

still plugging at my first rails program ever (Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0). Main model "Contact" should include a drop down in its form for "Color" table. I have added the Color model, created the html drop down and am trying to seed the Color model (drop down currently displays an empty menu). I am filling Color in seeds.rb from two arrays, and have verified that both arrays are full of string values (same vals as respective Color migration columns). When I attempt to put the array values into the Color table, it creates the right quantity of entries (my arrays are 140 elements in size each), but all entries are nil in both columns.

Below is my seeds.rb

Additional total noob question? How do I paste code into Stackoverflow on a linux machine instead of typing it?

```
colors = Array.new
colors = File.readlines("db/seeds/colornames.csv").map! {|name| name.chomp}

hexes = Array.new
hexes = File.readlines("db/seeds/colorhexes.csv").map! {|hex| hex.chomp}

Color.delete_all #because I keep having to reseed
x = 0
colors.each do |color|
  Color.create!(:name => color, :hex => hexes[x])
  x+=1
end
```

and the contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :zip_code, :favorite_color, :color_id #I have brought in the right gem to use this older method
  belongs_to :color 

  #validation of fields other than :favorite_color in here. Nothing pertinent to this q

  #favorite color validation
  validates_presence_of :favorite_color

end
```

and color.rb

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo here `"db/sees/colorhexes.csv"`

Comment: you should not need to use `attr_accessible` with rails 4 - the controller would use strong parameters instead of putting this on the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what your issue is by looking at the code, I recommend some poor mans debugging - `puts` is your friend

Also can you post your model code?

A few rubyish changes you could make to your code

- Array.new is rarely seen in ruby code, use `[]` instead, in this case no need to initialize the variable at all
- no need to call `map!` in this case, `map` will do
- Array (Enumerable) has a method `each_with_index` and you can avoid the x local
- use ruby 1.9 hash syntax

example

```
colors = File.readlines("db/seeds/colornames.csv").map {|name| name.chomp}
hexes = File.readlines("db/seeds/colorhexes.csv").map {|hex| hex.chomp}

Color.delete_all # because I keep having to reseed

colors.each_with_index do |color, index|
  Color.create!(name: color, hex: hexes[index])
end
```

now with some debugging

```
colors = File.readlines("db/seeds/colornames.csv").map {|name| name.chomp}
hexes = File.readlines("db/seeds/colorhexes.csv").map {|hex| hex.chomp}

puts "Color Count: #{colors.length}"
puts "Hex Count: #{hexes.length}"

Color.delete_all # because I keep having to reseed

colors.each_with_index do |color, index|
  puts "#{color}: #{hexes[index}"
  Color.create!(name: color, hex: hexes[index])
end    

puts "Loaded: #{Color.count} colors"
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already used puts, which is where I got as much info as I had. I did change my code to reflect your style reccs, thanks! Above I have now edited in my model code

Comment: so does `puts "#{color}: #{hexes[index}"` output values, but `Color.create!` does not set them?

Comment: Color.create! fills the table with nil values at this point, even though puts "#{color}: #{hexes[index}" puts out the right values, and puts color.class and puts hexes[index].class indicate that they are strings as expected.

Comment: try running this code, line by line from within rails console instead of via rake seed

Comment: It's true that at this point, I am getting a validation exception on presence_of. But I expected that to resolve itself after I got this drop down working. In console, Color.all reveals that 140 rows are being seeded with dual nil values

Comment: modify slightly to `x = Color.create!(...` and then `puts x.inspect`

Comment: also since you don't want colors with blank names, add a validation for that, which should cause the first record to fail inserting (if blank)

Comment: Ok,the transactions each include an error message at the bottom, and the very last transaction (oddly?) displays in console the entire contents of the colors array. I will continue with your other suggestions (modify, add validation), but below is the transaction error, which I will google: (0.1ms) begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms) INSERT INTO "colors" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
[["created_at", Sun, 13 Oct ...],  ["updated_at", Sun, ...]]
(7.2ms) commit transaction
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Color: name, hex

Comment: Thank you for teaching me to run each line in console. The transaction warning indicated that I was trying to fill some private variables. By putting an attr_accessible statement in BOTH models (whether that is the smart way to do it or not) the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Do You have this gem installed github.com/rails/protected_attributes ? If it's true, then You need to add as in Rails 3 this line to Your model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :hex
```